# Topological localisations of algebras and solidification

Tags: topological-vector-spaces, condensed-mathematics

Let $A$ be a (topologically discrete) commutative ring and consider the topological ring $A((z))$. Let $\underline{A((z))}$ denote the corresponding condensed ring, and let $a(z)$ be a non-zero element of $A((z))$. We can form the localisation $\underline{A((z))}[a(z)^{-1}]$ inside condensed rings as $(-)\otimes_{\mathbf{Z}[t]}\mathbf{Z}[t,t^{-1}]$.

**Question 1.** Is this isomorphic to the condensed ring corresponding to the localisation, $A((z))[a(z)^{-1}]$, taken inside topological rings? (Where we topologise the underlying abelian group as the colimit along multiplications by $a(z)$.)

**Question 2.** What is the solidification of $\underline{A((z))}[a(z)^{-1}]$? I am happy to assume that $A$ is an integral domain.

*Remark.* Note that $A((z))$ is already solid, but the localisation has no reason to be, as it is a colimit. If multiplication by $a(z)$ were an *open* map, then the localisation would also be solid. A natural guess for the solidification would be as follows; let $a(z)=az^{-n}+(\operatorname{higher order terms})$, and note that there is a natural map $A((z))[a(z)^{-1}]\rightarrow A[a^{-1}]((z))$ with dense image. The condensed ring corresponding to the right hand side is already solid, so perhaps this is the solidification.

Comment: 1: Yes. 2: It is already solid, as solid modules are stable under all colimits(!).